# Sapi5 on linux?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pywin32, win32com, pyttsx3

I am working on creating an AI for myself and I chose python as the programming language to code it in. I am an absolute beginner in programming and have very little knowledge of the subject. After spending months of coding I finally created an AI by myself that is able to run and I did so on windows. I wanted to move this program to a raspberry pi but turns out that I am unable to use Sapi5 TTS module from pyttsx3 on linux as it requires the win32com files to function. I am aware that pywin32 cannot be run on linux as it is a different OS and I want to know if there is a way for me to be able to run sapi5 on linux? I have tries using different tts modules such as espeak but they are too robotic and I really like sapi5 so it would be great if there was a way for me to be able to use it, thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

Sapi5 is a built-in part of Microsoft Windows and you can't run it in Linux. I agree it's a pretty good speech synthesizer. You may consider using [Mycroft/mimic](https://mycroft-ai.gitbook.io/docs/using-mycroft-ai/customizations/tts-engine), though I found the build process tricky, or use [gTTS](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/) if your utterances are short and you'll have internet access.